# Format number in java, which is the correct pattern

Tags: java, spring, database, format, numbers

Ciao, sorry for my english.

From the database I take a number, for example:
1,234.56
to the FE I have to send it like this: 1.234,56
how can I do? I try, but I can't.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try looking at the tutorial like this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: @AlexRudenko I have read before, but I have not solved.
malformed pattern: "###. ###, ##"

 public static final String PT = "###.###,##";
 

 public static DecimalFormat getAmountFormatter(Double value) {
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pt);
  df.format(value);
  return df;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You may use German or Italian locale like this to get custom formatting:

```java
float myNum = 1234.56f;
String formatted = String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%,8.2f", myNum);
```

Similarly, if you use custom DecimalFormat, you [need to switch to appropriate Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html):

```java
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ITALY);
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
        df.applyPattern("###,###.##");
        String output = df.format(myNum);
        System.out.println(output);
```

In the format pattern you cannot change group separator `,` and decimal separator `.`.